# I can't save parameter values for scheduled jobs in jasper server

Tags: job-scheduling, jasperserver

Please I have a problem in Jasper Server 7.8,  when I enter a parameter value in the scheduled reports and then save it, I got an empty report and every input control shows the default value.

How can I save my values in each parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem, If someone else has the same issue the solution is to apply the latest 7.8.0 hotfix.